# @Binding does not get a new value from the parent View

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, data-binding, swiftui

This is my parent view, where the key views for this question are the TextField for searching and the general view for displaying the list, which takes the query generated by the viewModel of the parent view.

```
struct SearchView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SearchViewModel()
    var body: some View {
    ...
                    CardStyleTextField(
                        textField: TextField("Search...",text: $viewModel.search),
                        imageName: "magnifyingglass"
    ...
                
                ArticleList(request: $viewModel.request)
            }
        }
    }
}

class SearchViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var request: Requestable = EverythingRequest(){
        didSet{
            print("SearchViewModel's request: \(request.makeQueryParams())")
        }
    }
    @Published var search = "" {
        didSet{
            print("SearchViewModel's search: \(search)")
            request.q = search
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the list view with its viewModel:

```
struct ArticleList: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ArticleListViewModel = ArticleListViewModel()
    @Binding var request: Requestable {
        didSet{
            print("ArticleList's request \(request)")
            viewModel.request = request
        }
    }
    var body: some View { }
}

class ArticleListViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var request: Requestable = EverythingRequest() {
        didSet{
            print("ArticleListViewModel's request \(request.makeQueryParams())")
            load()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the child view does not get the updated value.

Here is the console output:

- SearchViewModel's search: W
- SearchViewModel's request: q=W
- SearchViewModel's search: Wh
- SearchViewModel's request: q=Wh
- SearchViewModel's search: Why
- SearchViewModel's request: q=Why

Upd.

```
struct EverythingRequest: Requestable {
    let endpoint = "everything"
    var page: Int = 1
    var q: String = "" 
    ...

    func makeQueryParams() -> String {
        var query: [String] = []
        
        if !q.isEmpty{
            query.append("q=" + q)
        }
        ...
        let queryParams = query.joined(separator: "&")
        return queryParams
    }
```

Comment: Please add code of `EverythingRequest`, at least declaration part.

Comment: @Asperi, did it.